# property 'launchOptions' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate * in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swift, react-native, react-native-ios

My App is working fine on android but If I try to run it on the ios simulator then I am getting these errors:

```
error: illegal redeclaration of property in class extension 'AppDelegate' (attribute must be 'readwrite', while its primary must be 'readonly')
@property (nonatomic, strong) UMModuleRegistryAdapter *moduleRegistryAdapter;
^
In file included from /AppDelegate.m:8:
/AppDelegate.h:17:55: note: property declared here
@property(nonatomic, strong) UMModuleRegistryAdapter *moduleRegistryAdapter;
                                                      ^
/AppDelegate.m:30:8: error: property 'launchOptions' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'
  self.launchOptions = launchOptions;
       ^
/AppDelegate.m:50:83: error: property 'launchOptions' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:self.launchOptions];
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

#import <UMCore/UMModuleRegistry.h>
#import <UMReactNativeAdapter/UMNativeModulesProxy.h>
#import <UMReactNativeAdapter/UMModuleRegistryAdapter.h>

@interface AppDelegate () <RCTBridgeDelegate>
 
@property (nonatomic, strong) UMModuleRegistryAdapter *moduleRegistryAdapter;
 
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.moduleRegistryAdapter = [[UMModuleRegistryAdapter alloc] initWithModuleRegistryProvider:[[UMModuleRegistryProvider alloc] init]];
  self.launchOptions = launchOptions;

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
#ifdef DEBUG
  [self initializeReactNativeApp];
#else
  EXUpdatesAppController *controller = [EXUpdatesAppController sharedInstance];
  controller.delegate = self;
  [controller startAndShowLaunchScreen:self.window];
#endif


   [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

  return YES;
}


- (RCTBridge *)initializeReactNativeApp
{
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:self.launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"main" initialProperties:nil];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return bridge;
}

- (NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)extraModulesForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *extraModules = [_moduleRegistryAdapter extraModulesForBridge:bridge];
  // You can inject any extra modules that you would like here, more information at:
  // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html#dependency-injection
  return extraModules;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge {
#ifdef DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[EXUpdatesAppController sharedInstance] launchAssetUrl];
#endif
}

- (void)appController:(EXUpdatesAppController *)appController didStartWithSuccess:(BOOL)success
{
  appController.bridge = [self initializeReactNativeApp];
}

@end
```

My App is working fine on android without any issues these errors are what I am getting from the ios simulator only. I have tried clean build or pod install even deleting and reinstalling node_modules. But couldn't solve these issues.

I have followed this guide for [installing react-native unimodules](https://docs.expo.io/bare/installing-unimodules/) But I think maybe I have done something wrong for ios. How can I solve these issues?